# What do % signs mean in a url?

Tags: url

When I copy paste this Wikipedia article it looks like this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruy%C3%A8re_%28cheese%29

However if you paste this back into the URL address the percent signs disappear and what appears to be Unicode characters ( and maybe special URL characters ) take the place of the percent signs.

Are these abbreviations for Unicode and special URL characters?

I'm use to seeing \u00ff, etc. in JavaScript.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Encoding

Comment: Just tested in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. Only FF shows the URL decoded `(` and `)` in the address bar.

Comment: @stack_temp: It's not a 16x16 chart. Characters are encoded using UTF-8, then the hexadecimal representation of the bytes are the escape codes. The character `å` for example is encoded as two bytes and represented as `%C3%A5`.

Comment: @stack_temp: UTF-8 codes can be up to six bytes long, representing over 110,000 different characters. (It can represent over a million code points, but most of those are yet unused.)

Comment: and it is up to 4 bytes not 6 ... see ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: What was confusing is that `%` is two things, a method to include Unicode ( UTF - 8 ) and a way to escape special characters (into UTF-8 of course ).

Comment: `%` is not actually two things.  It is simply a way to escape bytes that are disallowed in URIs.  IRIs then define that to use Unicode, it must be encoded in UTF-8; it logically falls then to the percent-encoding to encode the result into URI-allowed characters.

Comment: @stack_temp: UTF8 converts Unicode codepoints to 8-bit bytes, then URI-encoding converts 8-bit bytes to pure ASCII text.  (which, ironically, is usually then stored as UTF8 or UTF16)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference you're looking for is [RFC 3987: Internationalized Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987), specifically [the section on mapping IRIs to URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-3.1).

[RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifies that reserved characters must be [percent-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1), but it *also* specifies that percent-encoded characters are decoded to US-ASCII, which does not include characters such as `è`.

RFC 3987 specifies that non-ASCII characters should first be encoded as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) so they can be percent-encoded as per RFC 3986.  If you'll permit me to illustrate in Python:

```
>>> u'è'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa8'
```

Here I've asked Python to encode the Unicode `è` to a string of bytes using UTF-8.  The bytes returned are `0xc3` and `0xa8`.  Percent-encoded, this looks like `%C3%A8`.

The parenthesis also appearing in your URL do fit in US-ASCII, so they are percent-escaped with their US-ASCII code points, which are also valid UTF-8.

So, no, there is no simple 16×16 table—such a table could never represent the richness of Unicode.  But there is a method to the apparent madness.

Comment: by definition there is a 16x16 table as you stated the encoding creates a form %HEXHEX.  Hexadecimal is 16 symbols and there are two of them.  I'm not sure why you thought I thought that this would cover all of unicode.  It would simply be a good starting point for reading the single %XX encodings.

Comment: @employee-0 You asked about how `è` became `%C3%A8` and vice-versa, which you need to use the above process to encode. And that process does not fit into a 16×16 table.

Comment: I didn't ask how to represent the richness of Unicode, but perhaps I did inadvertently, are you saying all %XX encodings in the URL are Unicode characters?

Comment: @employee-0 Your statements are confusing me.  Do you or do you not want to know how to represent characters like `è` that are not part of US-ASCII?

Comment: That was not a statement, it was a question.  Are all %XX encodings in the URL Unicode encodings?

Comment: @employee-0 Hey now, patience—this is a hobby, not a paying job.  I got your question, but it doesn't make sense to me—it seems you didn't understand my answer above.  I explained in fair detail how the percent-encoding process works.  Is something unclear?  Maybe background reading would help?  If so, follow the links I supplied, particularly the one about UTF-8.  Your key takeaway, IMO, should be that any given character in an IRI may be represented as not just one byte, but several.

Answer (score 4):

`%` in a *URI* is followed by two characters from `0-9A-F`, and is the escaped version of writing the character with that hex code. Doing this means you can write a *URI* with characters that might have special meaning in other languages.

Common examples are `%20` for a space and `%5B` and `%5C` for `[` and `]`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a different syntactical convention for what you're used to from JavaScript. URL syntax is simply different from that of JavaScript, in other words, and `%` is the way one introduces a two-hex-digit character code in that syntax.

Some characters *must* be escaped in order to be part of a URL/URI. For example, the `/` character has meaning; it's a **metacharacter**, in other words.  If you need a `/` in the middle of a path component (which admittedly would be a little weird), you'd have to escape it. It's analogous to the need to escape quote characters in JavaScript string constants.

Comment: @stack_temp because they're not allowed in URLs unless they're escaped.

Comment: @stack_temp it's just UTF-8; in other words, Unicode. Thus `%41` is the code for "A". In JavaScript, the `encodeURIComponent()` function will fix up URI path components so that they comply with the rules.

Comment: @stack_temp what do you mean by "escapes"?

Comment: @stack_temp no, you can't.  Like I said, URL/URI syntax is **different** from JavaScript syntax.  The `%` convention is the way to do escapes for URL/URI strings, in other words.

Comment: It is important to note the % sign servers two primary purposes.  One is to encode special characters and the other is to encode Unicode characters outside of what you can put in with your hardware/keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to note the % sign servers two primary purposes. One is to encode special characters and the other is to encode Unicode characters outside of what you can put in with your hardware/keyboard.  For example `%C3%A8` to encode `è`, and whatever encoding represents a forward slash `/`.

Using JavaScript we can create a encoding chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/CG8gx/3/

> ["\x00", "\x01", "\x02", "\x03", "\x04", "\x05",
>   "\x06", "\x07", "\b", "\t", "\n", "\v", "\f", "\r", "\x0E", "\x0F",
>   "\x10", "\x11", "\x12", "\x13", "\x14", "\x15", "\x16", "\x17",
>   "\x18", "\x19", "\x1A", "\x1B", "\x1C", "\x1D", "\x1E", "\x1F", " ",
>   "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".",
>   "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<",
>   "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
>   "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
>   "Y", "Z", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
>   "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
>   "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\x7F"]

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the technical details for this. But if you change the beginning of the URL so it is no longer recognized as a URL, it will copy & past correctly. For example, if you add or remove a character to the beginning of the url (when you do the copy), it will paste without the percent signs, as follows:
_ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruyère_cheese

Comment: It does not look like you included an example of a '%' sign in your answer along with an explanation.