# Why do some URL have funny characters like %20?

Tags: rest, url

I encountered a funny URL that looks something like this;

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888//echo/this%20is%20just%20a%20test
```

This makes the REST API looks weird. Is there some valid reason or is it just an eccentric habit of a programmer? Is it a good practice for REST APIs to avoid funny characters in the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do % signs mean in a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302178/what-do-signs-mean-in-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%20` means a `space` character and it's just [Percent-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), also known as [URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Certain characters, such as `space` characteres, are not allowed in URLs.
If a URL contains such characters, they need to be properly encoded.

Quoting the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) about Uniform Resource Identifier (URI):

> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
> component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
> allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
> component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
> triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
> hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
> example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
> "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
> character (SP).

Answer (score 1):

That is URL encoding of characters not allowed in a URL. `%20` is a blank space.

Comment: So, no REST API would use characters like %20?

Comment: I guess is not illegal to use them, but, as that decreases readability, probably is better to avoid it. You must have in mind %20 is not a character, but the encoding of it in a url.