# How do I fix the URL adding 20%20%20% to an appended URL

Tags: javascript

When add the vin to the URL, it also ads 20%20%20% to the URL. I just want the Vin added to the end of the URL.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var productNumber = document.getElementById('VIN').textContent;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href~="https://www.carfax.com/VehicleHistory/p/Report.cfx?vin="]'), function(link) {
    // if you want to change the link
    const currentHref = link.getAttribute('href');
    const newHref = currentHref + '#' + encodeURIComponent(productNumber);
    link.setAttribute('href', newHref);
    console.log(newHref);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="VIN">   123456</div>

<a href="https://www.carfax.com/VehicleHistory/p/Report.cfx?vin=">A link</a>
```

Comment: %20 is the url encoded version of a space. It means that the string you are appending to the url has three spaces that you need to trim before anything else

Comment: [Don't add details in comments](/help/how-to-ask), right now your comment is basically link spam and it might look like you wrote a post that sounds just credible enough for folks to click your link thinking there might be something related to the question there, but instead just end up being traffic to your website that earns you click revenue.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for the best experience here.

Comment: Try adding `trim` -> `var productNumber = document.getElementById('VIN').textContent.trim();`

Comment: I've revised your post to include a demo of your code (slightly modified for clarity into what's happening). Please revise as needed to show the situation accurately.

Comment: See [Why do some URL have funny characters like %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518574/why-do-some-url-have-funny-characters-like-20)